# JQuery Center Ooverflow DIV on Hover

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover

I am trying to replicate (in `JQuery/CSS`) [this flash site's](http://www.medianovak.com/) floating overflow boxes that center when the mouse is over.

Can someone point me in the right direction? this is the code I have so far, I have done some very simple and wrong `JQuery` code but I just don't know how to center my `divs` on hover.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">[NAV]</div>
    <div id="ContentPane" runat="server"></div>
</div>
<div id="front-floating-panes">
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-1" id="FloatingPane" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-2" id="FloatingPane2" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-3" id="FloatingPane3" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-4" id="FloatingPane4" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-5" id="FloatingPane5" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-floating-pane scroll-6" id="FloatingPane6" runat="server">
        <p>Pane 6</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#front-floating-panes{position:fixed; width:100%; margin: 25px 0 25px 25px; overflow:hidden;  white-space: nowrap; }
.front-floating-pane{border:1px solid; display:inline-block; width:350px; height:300px; margin: 0 10px 0 0; background-color:#29F;  }
.front-floating-pane p{ background-color:#F60;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scroll-1").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-20"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });

    $(".scroll-2").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-150"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });

    $(".scroll-3").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-200"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });

    $(".scroll-4").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-250"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });

    $(".scroll-5").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-300"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });

    $(".scroll-6").hover(
    function() {
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "-340"}, 200 );
    },
    function(){
        $("#front-floating-panes").stop().animate({ left : "0"}, 200 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the case that they 'centre' on hover, the floating-boxes container moves in the opposite direction as the mouse (try moving the mouse horizontally on any part of the window). So for example if the mouse moves 10px right, the container moves -10px left.

The relationship between the two values will be based on the screen size and the overflow of container size. Say you screen width is 960px and the overflow is 480px, then every 1px of mouse movement should move the contain half a pixel

These should help: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#How_do_I_find_the_mouse_position.3F
http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

(assuming that you want to replicate the effect, as opposed to centring elements on hover. If it is the latter you are after, you'd still need to grab mouseposition )